# Does "reputation scoring" make "the Torah a crown to magnify yourself with"?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, mussar-ethics, stackexchange

Is "[reputation scoring](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)"  against the spirit of [Pirkei Ovos 4](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682518/jewish/English-Text.htm) (5) "Rabbi Tzaddok would say: *Do not make the Torah a crown to magnify yourself with, ...."*

Comment: My oh my, I haven't seen a question with this many upvotes for quite a while... :-)

Comment: quite ironic :)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I was just about to say the same thing.  ;)

Comment: @Dave This is the second highest scoring question on the site :)

Comment: Just in case reputation scoring is forbidden, I downvoted this.

Comment: I don't understand what is <snip> , can you explain me? may be a wrong tag ? not clear. Very important topic! +1

Comment: @kouty It means I have cut out some text that is not relevant.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok thank you for the information. a very central topic. + 1 may be great discussions. What am I making when I write Q&R, reputation/limud. No money it is certain.

Comment: לעולם ילמד אדם שלא לשמה, שמתוך שלא לשמה בא לשמה.

Comment: To loosely quote Harav Yechiel Michel Feinstein Zt"l, halevai people would learn Torah for kavod.

Comment: Actually, to the contrary, Mi Yodeya is probably the only place you can learn Torah without the need to share your real identity

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The way I see reputation points on stack exchange is that they are useful for the people asking questions, not for the person getting the points.

That is, when someone comes to the site and asks a question, seeing the points next to a person's name gives that name 'recognition status'.  If there is a debate between two people, one has 1 point, and the other has 10,000 points. You might err on the side of the person with 10,000 points because they have 'proven' themselves.

Since the points, (I think) are intended to help people weigh answers, I don't think they count as a crown.

If however you are using the points as a crown, perhaps its a good idea to question yourself.

Comment: Just to add: they are also a nice way to say "thank you"

Comment: @yydl I agree, but the fact that it's preserved in public could be a drawback, from the point of view of the character development of the recipient.

Comment: As a result of the comments and answers posted, I suggest that "reputation scoring" is not in itself against the spirit of Pirkei Ovos 4 (5). But when I post, I should only do so out of a genuine desire to increase knowledge and not to increase my reputation.

Answer (score 45):

I do not think it is a problem for a few reasons. Kin'as sofrim tarbeh chochmah (jealousy among scholars will increase wisdom - Baba Basra 21a). A certain extent of competition in Torah is a good thing. Having people compete for even something as minor as points helps increase Torah and wisdom. There is an issue of a person becoming haughty or seeking honor because of his Torah knowledge, but I don't think this specific site would cause such a problem. This would probably be the conversation:

**High-ranking user**: Give me lots of honor.
**Regular guy**: Why?
**HRU**: I have 1000 points on Judaism.Stackexchange.com.
**RG**: On NASDAQ or NYSE?

The point is, no one is getting too much crown or glory from this site.

The commentators actually explain that Mishnah based on a Gemara in Nedarim (62a) that a person shouldn't learn so as to be called a sage or rabbi but he should learn out of love. 
I do not think that people are only learning Torah so they can know enough to answer questions on this site and get a high score. Even if that would happen, I think we would apply "לעולם יעסוק אדם בתורה ומצות אף על פי שלא לשמה שמתוך שלא לשמה בא לשמה". Ideally a person should learn lishmah, but he should use whatever motivations he can to learn before he's at that level.

Comment: Contrary to what you say about rep points' ability to gain you influence with regular guys (and if you've actually tried this, sorry), I think that the "shelo lishmah" aspect does exist, since approval from one's peers *within one's community*, which these points represent, is a powerful psychological motivator. That's why your points about kin'at soferim and "ba lishmah" are important ones.

Comment: Mi yodeya may not be as big as Stack Overflow (yet) but having a high reputation score _is_ what made [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) famous

Answer (score 1):

One argument that it would be "a crown to magnify yourself": the "Association reward" that a user recieves when they reach 200 reputation points on any stackexchange. Namely, they automatically get bumped up 100 points on any other stack exchange they join, in order to get them past the "basic user" stage, as they have proven themselves to "understand" the stackexchange community/style. I can imagine a person doing that on judaism.stackechange because they feel it is easier for them to get to 200 on MY than 100 on mathematics.stackexchange, and they want to be able to comment on posts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Making the Torah a crown to magnify yourself with isn't refering to how other score you. If you share knowledge and help people with it, it just shows the appreciation of the other and the value of the answers that been given. It is about the opposite, that someone would put on a crown (give himself a status/might) based on his or her knowledge of Torah to show off with it, place himself on a footstool and being arrogance, presumptuous or highhanded about it. A real rabbi is a real teacher, and a real teacher is teaching Torah not for his own benefit, but for the benefit of others, not out of love for hisself, but for the love to teach and out of the love for others. Although thats just my opinion.

Comment: But then perhaps we _shouldn't_ have reputation scoring. If we should teach out of the love to teach and the love for others, why do we need reputation points? Isn't that for ourselves?