# Saying magein avraham versus magein avram

Tags: words, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes

The *chazzan* is at the end of *Avos* (first bracha of Shmoneh Esrei) and he says, "...מגן אברם" (without the *hei*) instead of "...מגן אברהם," (with a *hei*). Would he be יוצא?

Comment: Unsourced: probably not

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35681 as well as several of the questions linked there. This is a special case where *B'rachos* 13a is also relevant (mentioned in DanF's answer), but I think this question hinges primarily on whether a problem is created with *shone mimatbei'a'* or changing the *nusach*.

Comment: Why is the question about the _chazan_ only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brachot 13a:

> תני בר קפרא כל הקורא לאברהם אברם עובר בעשה
>
> Bar Kaparah says someone who calls Avraham Avram "passes over" a
>   positive commandment

I infer, then, that this is problematic. Since the Gemarrah uses a "long" expression "Passes over a positive commandment" rather than stating "he sinned", it seems to mean that the person missed an opportunity to do a positive commandment, but it is not a sin, per se.

The best option, would probably be to speak to the Shat"z after davening and explain that he should correct the error next time.

Comment: Thanks a million! Sorry I don't have that type of money to give to you.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Who says that when you thank a million, it means money? How about a million mitzvot? Deal? :-) BTW, the answer, hopefully, made you "earn" your user ID.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah If you found the answer helpful, you could "pay" him an upvote. or even a checkmark.

Comment: @YEZ - Hey! Wouldn't that be profiting from Divrei Torah?

Comment: @DanF related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/does-reputation-scoring-make-the-torah-a-crown-to-magnify-yourself-with

Comment: @YEZ - Yes, I did see that discussion a while ago. Quite interesting. I have to re-read it. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: BTW, If you think "Magen Avram" is bad, I heard a Hassid say, "Ve'lokei Yankel"!