# PTIJ: Can I use M.Y. bounty as a means of Matanot L'evyonim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

*Matanot L'evyonim* is a Purim mitzvah to give gifts to at least 2 poor people.

An "evyon"  is described as "poor". But he could be "poor" in anything, not necessarily monetary means. There are a number of M.Y. members who *nebach* struggle to gain votes but just can't seem to make it to that next badge or milestone. B"H, He has blessed me with over 10K points, and I would like to be able to transfer some of these to assist two M.Y. members. But the only way I know to give them a quick bunch of points is by awarding them a bounty.

Would this be a halichically acceptable way of fulfilling *matanot l'evyonim*?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9445/5323

Comment: @Shokhet, I've wondered for a while if that applies to PTIJ, which doesn't necessarily rely on Torah stam.

Comment: Isn’t the whole point of Matanos L’Evyonim to buy food for the Purim Seudah? (Also, the irony in putting a bounty on this question...)

Answer (score 5):

Mishna Torah, Hilchos Megillah and Chanukah (perek 2 Halacha 16):

וְחַיָּב לְחַלֵּק לָעֲנִיִּים בְּיוֹם הַפּוּרִים. אֵין פּוֹחֲתִין מִשְּׁנֵי עֲנִיִּים נוֹתֵן לְכָל אֶחָד  מַתָּנָה אַחַת אוֹ מָעוֹת אוֹ מִינֵי תַּבְשִׁיל אוֹ מִינֵי אֳכָלִין שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (אסתר ט כב) "וּמַתָּנוֹת לָאֶבְיוֹנִים", שְׁתֵּי מַתָּנוֹת לִשְׁנֵי עֲנִיִּים.

We see from here that giving a “matanah” is considered matanot l’evyonim

And as it says in meseches chagiga (daf 5b)
 מי ידעיתו כמה מתנות - Mi Yodeya (is equal to) a couple of presents

Therefore, giving on Mi Yodeya isn’t just considered matanos l’evyonim, it’s considered even better than matanos l’evyonim!